# Can't get Last.FM API PHP Proxy to work

Tags: php, javascript, proxy, jsonp, last.fm

I'm trying to regularly retrieve JSON album data from the Last.FM API, and since they don't support JSONP I'm using a PHP Proxy to circumvent the cross-domain limitation. Here's my PHP proxy:

```
<?php
$artist = $_GET["artist"];
$album = $_GET["album"];
$content = file_get_contents('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=APIKEY=' . $artist . '&album=' . $album . '&format=json');
echo $content;
?>
```

As you can see I'm using GET to specify the artist and album, so the URL would look like `albumartproxy.php?artist=Jake%20Bugg&album=Jake%20Bugg`

But for some reason I get the following error when I try to run the proxy:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=037358e302c80571663e6a7a66b1dc05&artist=Jake Bugg&album=Jake Bugg&format=json) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! in /MYDOMAIN/albumartproxy.php on line 6
```

When I access the API URL directly it works? Can someone help? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to urlencode the artist name etc. does it help?

Comment: Yes! You're the best! Submit it as an answer!

Comment: Just FYI, the Last.fm API does in fact do support JSONP requests: http://www.last.fm/api/rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to [`urlencode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the GET parameters that you are passing along with the request.

Answer (score 0):

You need urlencode() the `GET`s, like so:

```
<?php

$apikey = "273f3dc84c2d55501f3dc25a3d61eb39";

$artist = urlencode($_GET["artist"]);
$album = urlencode($_GET["album"]);
$autocorrect = 0;

$content = "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=".$apikey."&artist=".$artist."&album=".$album."&autocorrect=".$autocorrect;

echo file_get_contents($content);

?>
```

**Sample output:** http://pastie.org/8114551

Hope this helps!